# Creating help page on DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

My goal is creating help section like on http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction.html with cascade menu folding on DotNetNuke. Should I use DNN standard tools or special module? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways of doing this, however, the management overhead is really going to dictate how to do this.

One option would be to simply create individual pages for each section, then create a skin with the proper menu style to handle the left side process.  Honestly, this is the "easiest" way of doing it.  But if you have a lot of documentation this could take a while.

Another option would be to see if there is a way to re-purpose another module to help with this.  News Articles from Ventrian with Categories could help, but you would need a fair bit of work to get the "Tree" style behavior to the left.

Comment: Creating individual pages to do all of this would be the WORST way to do this :D from a content management perspective

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start by looking at the News Articles module from Ventrian for a project like that.